# iMessage like gradient mask in css

Tags: jquery, css

I have a calendar where I would like calendar entries to reflect a gradient displayed behind the calendar just like the iMessages in iOS7 are lighter towards the top and darker at the bottom. Is this possible to accomplish in css3?

I would organize it as follows (simplified 2 day calendar):

```
<div class="gradient">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li class="masked-gradient-background" >lighter item</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li class="masked-gradient-background" >darker item item</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it working by using the scroll event to adjust the background position of all the list elements with Jquery:

```
$('li').each(function(){
  var li_offset = $(this).offset().top
  $(this).css('background-position', '0 '+li_offset+'px');
});

$('.scroll').scroll(function(){
  $('li').each(function(){
    var scroll_offset = $(this).scrollTop();
    var li_offset = $(this).offset().top
    var total = li_offset - scroll_offset
    $(this).css('background-position', '0 '+total+'px');
  });
});
```

## **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zDWc3/1/)**

thanks @vals for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

In the solution that I can give you, you need to know before hand how many items there will be, and write a rule for every item.

Not the best idea, may be somebody can do it better.

CSS

```
.masked-gradient-background {
    background-size: 100px 300%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg,white, black);
}

tr:nth-child(1) .masked-gradient-background {
    background-position-y: 0%;
}

tr:nth-child(2) .masked-gradient-background {
    background-position-y: -100%;
}

tr:nth-child(3) .masked-gradient-background {
    background-position-y: -200%;
}
```

You need to know the number of items to set the 300% in the background-size. Unless is ok for you to go for the maximum number, and if the list is halfway full, the last items won't be full dark

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zDWc3/)

Comment: hmm yes @vals, this would be half of what I am trying to accomplish,  I wonder if there would be an efficient way to sync the background-position to a user scrolling with jquery? Maybe somehow syncing the background position of each calendar entry to the offset().top of that element.

Comment: Not really sure how are you handling scroll. Maybe you can supply a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't the same as in the Message.app this is the gradient from the mail.app

http://jsfiddle.net/cHhN2/

```
<div class="icon mail"></div>

html, body {
width   : 100%;
height  : 100%;
margin  : 0;
padding : 0; }

.icon {
position           : relative;
display            : inline-block;
width              : 100px;
height             : 100px;
margin             : 20px;
border-radius      : 18px;
-webkit-box-sizing : border-box;
-moz-box-sizing    : border-box;
box-sizing         : border-box; }

.mail {
box-shadow : 0 0 0 1px rgba(11, 70, 238, 0.1) inset;
background : -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1a51f0 0%, #03e4fe 100%);
background : -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1a51f0 0%, #03e4fe 100%);
background : -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1a51f0 0%, #03e4fe 100%);
background : -o-linear-gradient(top, #1a51f0 0%, #03e4fe 100%);
background : linear-gradient(top, #1a51f0 0%, #03e4fe 100%); }

.mail {
position      : absolute;
width         : 68px;
height        : 46px;
top           : 50%;
left          : 50%;
margin        : -23px 0 0 -34px;
overflow      : hidden;
border-radius : 3px;
box-shadow    : 0 0 0 1px rgba(5, 64, 234, 0.1); }


.mail:before {
top          : 0;
left         : 0;
border-color : transparent transparent transparent white; }

.mail:after {
top          : 0;
right        : 0;
border-color : transparent white transparent transparent; }

.mail {
position : absolute; }
```

Although this may not be what you are asking, if not please post a screenshot as I am an Android user and I will look to help where I can.

Comment: The effect he’s looking for is for a static gradient from the top to the bottom of the page, where objects moving on the page act as cutouts revealing the gradient. So a box at the top of the screen would shade from one blue to another as you scroll it to the bottom. This doesn’t look like it would accomplish that.